# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing this weird crash on prod on recycler view while recycling the items and  I am not able to reproduce this crash also.

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool!
   at androidx.core.util.Pools$SimplePool.release(Pools.java:117)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.recycleUpdateOp(AdapterHelper.java:743)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.recycleUpdateOpsAndClearList(AdapterHelper.java:750)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.consumePostponedUpdates(AdapterHelper.java:123)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.consumeUpdatesInOnePass(AdapterHelper.java:557)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags(RecyclerView.java:3585)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3829)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1877)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5044)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

Comment: so no stacktraces related to your app code?

Comment: @user158 no stacktraces related to app

Comment: If you on latest RV version move back to an older version,otherwise move to a newer version.

Comment: @user158 this is the newer version of androidX

Comment: what is the RV version?

Comment: Put the adapter code

Comment: @user158  androidXRecyclerView : "1.0.0"

Comment: try `1.1.0-beta03`

Comment: @PavanBilagi Does the following answer fix the issue?

Comment: @user158 No it is not fixing the issue

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622657/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-perform-this-operation-because-the-conne

Comment: @VibhanshuSharma the mentioned link is not the proper answer

Comment: do you have custom implementation of touches in your view?@Pavan Bilagi

Comment: This look interesting: at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5044) Perhaps this crash happens during a fling?

Comment: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074907/velocitytracker-causes-crash-on-android-4-4 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541619/android-recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchanged-getting-illegalstateexception-a

Comment: on which scenario you're getting this issue

Comment: Have you found the root cause? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

The exception is thrown when two different threads are trying to reach your recycle view instance to update it.

Let's clarify it. assume Thread A goes to update your recycle view Then next Thread B tries to do the same as A. as a result, Exception thrown, says A already in the pool (`Already in the pool!`)

after some researches, to find the solution, I found these approaches

[Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

```
synchronized(recycleview)
{

}
```

[Pools.SynchronizedPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Pools.SynchronizedPool)

using `androidx.core.util.Pools.SynchronizedPool<T>` instead of `androidx.core.util.Pools.SimplePool`

both approaches try to synchronize accessing critical sections to avoid throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the recyclerView while it is computing. 
You should do something like this:

```
if (recyclerView != null) {
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyDataSetChange(); //whatever you use, insert, remove, itemChanged etc...
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of problem for my case was

`thisRecycler?.getRecycledViewPool()?.clear()` called too frequently that synchronous operations weren't performed on this line

It was introduced as alternative to

```
notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, previousContentSize)
.
.
notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newRecyclerContent.size - 1)
```

Now the code is stable with usage of

```
notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, previousContentSize)
.
.
notifyDataSetChanged()
```